# jQuery fade in/out replaced text removes link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4HCQ/)

This works correctly as it should when it comes to the fadeIn/out part however the `h1` child being the a `href` tag gets removed on `hover` - I want to keep the **a** tag.

This also causes trouble with -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; -webkit-background-clip: text; so if I would animate the a tag it would cause a jumpy animation (chrome). However I've discovered that if I animate the parent being h1 the animation runs smoothly

structure as it should be:

```
<div id="heroburrito">
    <div class="vert">
         <h1>
            <a class="homehover" href="#"></a>  <!--This parts gets removed on hover - it shouldn't-->
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#heroburrito .vert h1 a.homehover').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(660, function () {
        $(this).text('←retreat').fadeIn().addClass('home').idle(200);
    });
},

function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(660, function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).fadeIn().removeClass('home');
    });
});
```

Comment: That is a strange way of implementing css. It is quicker and easier to view if you set class or id then put the css in the css box

Comment: @OliverCole Sorry this was taken straight from the WP theme I'm doing.  Where I control the CSS using PHP - check this link http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/portfolio/?portfolio=konsthallen

Comment: It's not strange way @Oliver, it's one of the way (Inline Styles). The only benefit is that they have highest precedence, these styles will be applied no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are using `$(this).text(...)` - this replaces the entire content of the element referred to by `this` - which is your `h1` element.  Instead, you should attach the code to your `a` element inside the `h1`:

```
$('#heroburrito .vert h1 a.homehover').hover(...)
```

This is correct in your question, but your fiddle only contained

```
$('#heroburrito .vert h1').hover(...)
```

thus replacing your entire link with the plain text.  Here's my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4HCQ/13/) that works correctly.

**EDIT:** if you need to run the fade in/out on `h1` instead of the link itself, then you need to apply the text change to the link - here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4HCQ/27/):

```
$('#heroburrito .vert h1').hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
        $('a.homehover', this).text('←retreat');
        $(this).fadeIn().addClass('home')
    });
},

function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
        $('a.homehover', this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText'));
        $(this).fadeIn().removeClass('home');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. Sorry I probably should have mentioned this in post - however this causes trouble with -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; -webkit-background-clip: text; as you can see in your fiddle the text fadeIn/Out is quite jumpy in chrome. However if you animate the h1 instead of the anchor tag it fades out/in smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#heroburrito .vert h1').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {
    $(':first-child:not',this).fadeOut(200, function () {
        $(this).text('←retreat').fadeIn().addClass('home');
    });
},
function () {
    $(':first-child:not',this).fadeOut(200, function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).fadeIn().removeClass('home');
    });
});
```

This will keep the `a` element intact.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/n4HCQ/15/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined jquery.js?ver=1.8.3:2 I get that error

Answer (score 0):

I edited the JSFiddle to fix the issue where you're changing the innerText of the h1, instead of the innerText of the a tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4HCQ/14/

You should be doing

```
$(this).find("a").text('←retreat');
$(this).fadeIn().addClass('home');
```

Instead of

```
$(this).text('←retreat').fadeIn().addClass('home').idle(200);
```